# Create a JMS message as JSON

Tags: spring, spring-jms, spring-test

Is there a way I can build the JMS message as JSON type. I need to create a JSON message for testing. There are a lot of attributes so i don't want to set them individually and create  object and then convert it to JSON.  Any other way (say) I read the json file and create a Message and then send to a JMS Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in JMS message(body), you could send the JSON.

```
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
// We will send a small text message saying 'Hello World!'
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(" { "\name"\:"\John"\, "\age"\:31, "\city"\:"\New York"\ }");
// Here we are sending the message!
producer.send(message);
System.out.println("Sent message '" + message.getText() + "'");
```

Comment: I tried this way already. The problem is that on listening this message when I try to convert it to Object using jackson library it throws Class Cast exception as textmessage can't be converted to the object. The jackson is defined as: @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("DomainClassName");
        return converter;

Comment: Its different problem now, you have sent JSON Message, all is well on message produce side. On the consumer end you have to do following, `Message message = consumer.receive(1000);
 
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    String text = textMessage.getText();
                    System.out.println("Received: " + text);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Received: " + message);
                }` . Now, you have JSON Test in text, do Jackson magic now.